# android app crashes when I click on a menu item

Tags: android, xml, firebase

So i"m kinda a newbie in android development and and im having a problem with a menu item.This menu item is suppose to direct me to a screen that shows a wordpress api which are listing of news items so I'm not sure whats wrong,so i dont know is my routing wrong or is it the code that crashes my app when routing and how routing goes is that theres a news_article_activity which connects with the app_bar_news_article.xml which then connects to content_news_article.xml.

```
  

      public class NewsArticle extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Constants {
        String url = "https://www.wiggletunes.co.za/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=10&fields=id,title";
        List<Object> list;
        Gson gson;
        ListView postList;
        Map<String,Object> mapPost;
        Map<String,Object> mapTitle;
        int postID;
        String postTitle[];
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.news_article_activity);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    
            //This is the drawer code
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
    
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            //End of drawer code
    
            makeDraw();
    
        }
    
        public void makeDraw(){
            try {
                postList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.postLists);
    
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        gson = new Gson();
                        list = (List) gson.fromJson(s, List.class);
                        postTitle = new String[list.size()];
    
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                            mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) list.get(i);
                            mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                            postTitle[i] = (String) mapTitle.get("rendered");
                        }
    
                        postList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(NewsArticle.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, postTitle));
    
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(NewsArticle.this, "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    
                RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NewsArticle.this);
                rQueue.add(request);
    
                postList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) list.get(position);
                        postID = ((Double) mapPost.get("id")).intValue();
    
                        Intent intent = new Intent(NewsArticle.this, NewsArticlePost.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id", "" + postID);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    
            int id = item.getItemId();
    
    
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    
        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
    
    
            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
    
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(NewsArticle.this, RadioActivity.class);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    
    
            }   else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
    
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(NewsArticle.this, NewsActivity.class);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
    
    
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(MENU_SITE_URL));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
    
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
    
    
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(NewsArticle.this, FeedbackActivity.class);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    
            } else if(id == R.id.nav_podcast){
    
    
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(NewsArticle.this, PodcastActivity.class);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    
    
    
    
            }  else if(id == R.id.nav_social){
    
    
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(NewsArticle.this, SocialActivity.class);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    
    
            }else if(id==R.id.nav_shop) {
    
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(NewsArticle.this, ShopActivity.class);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    
            }else if(id==R.id.nav_article) {
    
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(NewsArticle.this, NewsArticle.class);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    
            }
    
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    
    
    
    }

This is the xml files for routing
```

````
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="info.appteve.lavradio.NewsArticle"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_news_article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="@drawable/back_i"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/textMenu"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/textMenu"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle" />

         </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```
````

heres the app_bar_news_article.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="info.appteve.lavradio.NewsArticle"
    android:background="#151515">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_news_article" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Heres the content_news-article.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backlav2"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="info.appteve.lavradio.NewsArticle"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_news_article">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adViewNews"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/postLists"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewNews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

LOG CAT

```
2021-01-29 10:01:26.556 21363-21363/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-01-29 10:01:26.558 21363-21363/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2021-01-29 10:01:26.630 21363-21363/? E/ppteve.lavradi: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-01-29 10:01:27.976 21363-21424/info.appteve.lavradio E/OneSignal: Waiting for remote params. Moving onAppLostFocus() operation to a pending task queue.
2021-01-29 10:01:29.120 21363-21405/info.appteve.lavradio E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
2021-01-29 10:01:29.127 21363-21397/info.appteve.lavradio E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:69)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:23)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:51)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:32)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:13)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:167)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzag.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:14)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:166)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzk.then(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:353)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doGetId$1(FirebaseInstallations.java:296)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$3.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
2021-01-29 10:01:29.401 21363-21400/info.appteve.lavradio E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: FIS_AUTH_ERROR. Won't retry the operation.
2021-01-29 10:01:29.524 21363-21405/info.appteve.lavradio E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
2021-01-29 10:01:35.378 21363-21829/info.appteve.lavradio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
    Process: info.appteve.lavradio, PID: 21363
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:108)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.appteve.lavradio-xdWsxKentxkH8LtFjfBZSg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/info.appteve.lavradio-xdWsxKentxkH8LtFjfBZSg==/lib/arm, /data/app/info.appteve.lavradio-xdWsxKentxkH8LtFjfBZSg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:108) 
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93) 
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105) 
2021-01-29 10:01:35.847 21363-21363/info.appteve.lavradio E/ActivityThread: Activity info.appteve.lavradio.RadioActivity has leaked ServiceConnection info.appteve.lavradio.radio.RadioManager$1@5665d1d that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity info.appteve.lavradio.RadioActivity has leaked ServiceConnection info.appteve.lavradio.radio.RadioManager$1@5665d1d that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1924)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcherCommon(LoadedApk.java:1796)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1775)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1793)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1722)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:719)
        at info.appteve.lavradio.radio.RadioManager.bind(RadioManager.java:53)
        at info.appteve.lavradio.RadioActivity.onResume(RadioActivity.java:398)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1454)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4616)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4659)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: post your logcat so peoples can see what is the actual error.

Comment: @UsamaAltaf my logcat isn't that helpful it doesn't show the error on the file

Comment: @UsamaAltaf added the log cat,please tell me if you see the error

Comment: Looks like your firebase configuration is the problem.